How To Create A Bootstrapper Using Wix Toolset
We have a msi which requires a exe file which we need to execute to ensure the user has the correct license key but we do not want to include the exe within the msi and we need to run this exe file before installing the actual files i know we can do this using the wix bootstrapper (Burn) But i can't understand how.
i have tried creating a c# application which will copy the file from my machine to the client machine but it does not work because it requires the exe file to be present in the clients machine to copy that file in another directory


Make MSI file, which will install your .exe in client machine.
Make wix Bootstrapper (using Wix VS Extension). Put in the chain first MSI with .exe and second the main MSI.
Call .exe from main MSI in a custom action.


can give me a link to some articles that explain how i can make wix bootstrapper
